# How does distribution key allocate data in segments for GreenPlum

Tags: greenplum

I understand that Greenplum Database will separate data into different segments according to table distribution key. And furthermore, from the [documentation](https://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/6-1/admin_guide/distribution.html) it says:

*To achieve local joins for large tables commonly joined together, distribute the tables on the same column.*

Assume there are tables as follow:

1. T_1 contains key external columns (a,b)
2. T_2 contains key external columns (a)
3. T_3 contains key external columns (b)

So if I distribute T_1 by both (a,b), how should I distribute T_2 and T_3 in order to achieve maximum localization of a join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't distribute T_2 and T_3 the same way as T_1, because you are missing columns in each table.

In your scenario you can either optimize T_2 by distributing T_1 by (a), or optimize T_3 by distributing T_1 by (b). And you have to use the same data types as well.